# How to call a method defined in Java from Scala program?

Tags: java, scala

I'm new to Scala, in below code I want to return a `tokenRequest`, but I got error "Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `TokenRequest`", what is the correct way to do that?

```
private def makeTokenRequest(format: String, provider: String, scopes: String, audience: String, clientAuthentication: ClientAuthentication): TokenRequest = {
        val tokenRequest: TokenRequest = null
        val uri = new URI(baseUrl + "?provider=" + provider + "&format=" + format)
        val params = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, List[String]]
        if (audience != null) {
            params.put("audience", List(audience))
        }
        if (scopes != null) {
            tokenRequest = new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, Scope.parse(""), null, params)
//Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `TokenRequest`
        } else {
            tokenRequest = new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, null, null, params)
//Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `TokenRequest`
        }
        tokenRequest
    }
```

This is the correct doc
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/6.23/com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/TokenRequest.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.net.URI,com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.auth.ClientAuthentication,com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.AuthorizationGrant,com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.Scope,java.util.List,java.util.Map)

Comment: How do you define the `TokenRequest`?

Comment: I think that in both case above you are using a constructor with 6 arguments. There is no such constructor in the link you provide!

Comment: public TokenRequest(URI uri, ClientAuthentication clientAuth, AuthorizationGrant authzGrant, Scope scope, List<URI> resources, Map<String, List<String>> customParams) this is the one in source code

Comment: Well there is definitely no constructor with 6 arguments in that documentation. Are you sure you're using the right version? Or maybe documentation version is not same as the one you're using in the application?

Comment: Also note that since you've declared `tokenRequest` to be a `val`, you can't assign to it later.

Comment: From the error, I would guess that there are actually two constructors that match the number of arguments provided, with different types. Because some arguments are `null`, the compiler can't tell what the type is and therefore doesn't know which constructor to choose. This is all just speculation, though, unless we can see the definition of `TokenRequest`.

Comment: @Filip I updated the correct doc

Comment: @TimMoore I updated the correct doc, there's no tow constructors have the same number of arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I added this code and dependency to my own IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), I also see the error "Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `TokenRequest`".

Running `sbt compile` reveals different errors:

1. First: "reassignment to val" (as Levi Ramsey pointed out in the comments on the question):

   ```
   [error] /Users/tmoore/Projects/scala-scratch/src/main/scala/Test.scala:21:20: reassignment to val
   [error]       tokenRequest = new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, Scope.parse(""), null, params)
   [error]                    ^
   [error] /Users/tmoore/Projects/scala-scratch/src/main/scala/Test.scala:24:20: reassignment to val
   [error]       tokenRequest = new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, null, null, params)
   [error]                    ^
   [error] two errors found
   [error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
   ```

   This can fixed by changing `tokenRequest` to a `var`, or more idiomatically, removing the declaration for `tokenRequest` and allowing it to be returned directly from the `if`/`else` expressions.
2. Type mismatch for `params`:

   ```
   [error] /Users/tmoore/Projects/scala-scratch/src/main/scala/Test.scala:20:102: type mismatch;
   [error]  found   : java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,List[String]]
   [error]  required: java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[String]]
   [error]       new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, Scope.parse(""), null, params)
   [error]                                                                                                      ^
   [error] /Users/tmoore/Projects/scala-scratch/src/main/scala/Test.scala:23:91: type mismatch;
   [error]  found   : java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String,List[String]]
   [error]  required: java.util.Map[String,java.util.List[String]]
   [error]       new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, null, null, params)
   [error]                                                                                           ^
   [error] two errors found
   ```

   This happens because `params.put("audience", List(audience))` uses `scala.collection.immutable.List`, which does not implement `java.util.List`. You'll need to change the type of `params` to `new ConcurrentHashMap[String, java.util.List[String]]`.

   You can convert `List(audience)` to a Java list by importing the conversion with  `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` and then calling `List(audience).asJava`. See the Scala documentation on [Conversions Between Java and Scala Collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) for details.

   Alternatively, you could build a Java list in the first place by importing `java.util.Collections` and using `Collections.singletonList`. For this example, I'm using this approach.

Here's the final code, which compiles in `sbt` and shows no errors in the editor:

```
import com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.{ClientCredentialsGrant, Scope, TokenRequest}
import com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.auth.ClientAuthentication

import java.net.URI
import java.util.Collections
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

class Test {
  val baseUrl: String = ???

  private def makeTokenRequest(format: String, provider: String, scopes: String, audience: String, clientAuthentication: ClientAuthentication): TokenRequest = {
    val uri = new URI(baseUrl + "?provider=" + provider + "&format=" + format)
    val params = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, java.util.List[String]]
    if (audience != null) {
      params.put("audience", Collections.singletonList(audience))
    }
    if (scopes != null) {
      new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, Scope.parse(""), null, params)
    } else {
      new TokenRequest(uri, clientAuthentication, new ClientCredentialsGrant, null, null, params)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looking at this again, there's no real reason to use `ConcurrentHashMap` in this context, since it isn't being modified by multiple threads as far as I can tell. I'll leave the answer as is, because changing that isn't necessary to get this to compile, but it's something else you might want to consider. It also seems strange that the contents of `scopes` aren't used. It's only checked for `null` and then ignored.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful